# How to cut off a connected user ID from IBM MessageSight?

Tags: mqtt

How can I kick out a user that is already connected to IBM MessageSight (MQTT)?
This is the scenario:

1. a device is initially connected to MQTT with a user ID (eg. sensor02)
2. I remove the user ID (eg. sensor02) from MessageSight
3. sensor02 can no longer establish new connection --> this is totally expected behaviour
4. The original connection is still alive and the device keeps publishing data to MessageSight --> this somehow is not expected, I was expecting to see the connection being cut off as soon as the user ID is removed from MessageSight

So if removing user ID does not cut off existing connections, how can I get it done? Any command or API for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a way to disconnect the user.  See these examples which are different based on if you are using v1.2 or v2.0 Beta

In V1.2 - refer to the following Knowledge Center topic on "imaserver close Connection" call.
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSCGGQ_1.2.0/com.ibm.ism.doc/Reference/SecurityCmd/cmd_imaserver_close_connection.html?lang=en

In v2.0, use [REST API to close a connection](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSWMAJ_2.0.0/com.ibm.ism.doc/Reference/SecurityCmd/cmd_imaserver_close_connection.html):

HTTP Method: `POST`
URI: `ima/v1/service/close/connection`
Payload:

```
{
    "UserID":"string",
    "ClientID":"string",
    "ClientAddress":"string"
}
```

curl Example:

```
curl -X POST http://10.10.129.1:9089/ima/v1/service/close/connection -d '{ "ClientAddress":"180.43.2.1", "UserID":"glenn", "ClientID":"xxxx" }'
```